# Advance search system in asp.net web pages

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to create advance search option like that of google page in asp web pages. To be more clear. I'll give the example of my requirement.

In google home page. if in the textbox you type IN.. below you will get various options that start with IN like INDIA,INNOVA etc.

Is it possible to do in asp web page where the code is in C#.

Also is it possible to use it without using Ajax or any other higher level architecture programs?

Comment: im new to this programming field so mistook ajax as program. any ways im looking for the solution

Comment: You'll have to check AJAX also, you can't accomplish this feature without AJAX (ajaxcontroltoolkit for the easy way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at ajax control toolkit 
[AutoComplete Control](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx).